# Concatenate the columns from two result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `group`

```
CREATE TABLE
GROUP (id , HOST , participant)

INSERT INTO GROUP(id, HOST, participant)
VALUES (1, 1000, 2000)

INSERT INTO GROUP (id, HOST, participant)
VALUES (1, 1000, 2000)
```

`customer` table

```
insert into customer( custmerid, customername, alias) values (1000,'abccorp', 'abc')
insert into customer( custmerid, customername, alias) values (2000,'bcacorp', 'bca')
insert into customer( custmerid, customername, alias) values (3000,'lcacorp', 'lca')
```

Now I want to write a view to get

```
groupID, host participation
1 abccorp bcacorp
2 abccorp null
3 null lcacorp
```

How can I get this? I see that there are two joins needed to the organisation. But how can I get it ??

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is something awry with your demo values. How would one get groupID 2 and 3 as they are not in your example. Your definition of the [GROUP] table is invalid (missing data types) and appears to double enter the same 2 rows of data. Finally, how does organization/customer tie to [GROUP]

Comment: How are `Customer` and `Group` connected?? There's no obvious connection based on a column of the same name..... you need to explain a bit more!!

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstood your question, following statement would return the results you require.

#### I am using following assumptions

- `Host` is mapped to `custmerid`
- `Participant` is mapped to `custmerid`
- The input data you provided is incomplete

Note that if `custmerid` isn't a spelling error in your question, I would advice you to spell it out completely as `customerid`

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  groupid = g.id
        , host = chost.customername
        , participation = cparticipant.customername     
FROM    [Group] g
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer chost ON chost.custmerid = g.Host
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer cparticipant ON cparticipant.custmerid = g.Participant
```

#### Test Data

```
;WITH [Group](ID, Host, Participant) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1000, 2000
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1000, NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, NULL, 3000
)
, Customer (custmerid, customername, alias) AS (
    SELECT 1000, 'abccorp', 'abc'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2000, 'bcacorp', 'bca'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3000, 'lcacorp', 'lca'
)
SELECT  groupid = g.id
        , host = chost.customername
        , participation = cparticipant.customername     
FROM    [Group] g
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer chost ON chost.custmerid = g.Host
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer cparticipant ON cparticipant.custmerid = g.Participant
```

#### Output

```
groupid     host    participation
----------- ------- -------------
1           abccorp bcacorp
2           abccorp NULL
3           NULL    lcacorp
```